# Occasional EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSUserDefaults access or synchronize

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, exc-bad-access

In a tab-based app when I switch between some tabs, I *sometimes* get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  It's not every time but if you flick back and forward a few times it eventually happens.

Defined in the .h:

`NSUserDefaults *theData;`

I've got this in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear:

`[theData synchronize];`

The line at fault gets called in a function at the viewWillAppear stage:

`NSMutableArray *thisArray = [theData objectForKey:@"FriendsArray"];`

I'm using NSUserDefaults to store a few dictionaries of data.  This is populated by server calls, but there's no need for an internal database due to it being refreshed often.  I am open to other ways of storing this data if that would be better.

I have tried a number of things like casting it `(NSMutableArray *)[theData objectForKey:@"FriendsArray"];` or using `arrayForKey` and a number of other things with no improvement.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're certain that it's todo with the nsuserdefaults stuff then you might want to check whether you're erroneously releasing stuff you're putting in or taking out of defaults.

Comment: it looks like somehow theData has gone away and you're trying to access it.  Can you add more info/code around how you handle *theData?  How do you init it and clean it up?

Comment: Oops, theData is initialised in `viewDidLoad()` like this `theData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray = [theData objectForKey:@"FriendsArray"]; // retain
```

The way you try to make an array mutable is wrong. Also written like that, as suggested in the comments, you should probably retain that array.

Try init/alloc a new mutable array with objects like this :

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray =
 [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[theData objectForKey:@"FriendsArray"]];
```

Another method, [`-(id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array copyItems:(BOOL)flag;`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html), allows you to make a copy of the original objects.

Comment: I'm now casting the `NSMutableArray` to `NSArray` before saving it in `NSUserDefaults`.  Then when I pull it out I'm getting it as an `NSArray` and casting it to an `NSMutableArray` if required.  Also `retain` -ing too and there's no more crashes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Values in NSUserDefaults can not be mutable. You are trying to cast an immutable object into a mutable one. Try casting it into an NSArray, then cast that back into a mutable array. Should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason for using

```
NSUserDefaults *theData;
```

Instead use this to recover a mutable array from UserDefaults:

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray =
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FriendsArray"] mutableCopy];
```

This gives you a RETAINED mutable array.

Note also that you only need to use synchronize when saving to UserDefaults, not when reading. You should synchronize pretty much after every save since your app can crash or be shut down by the iOS without you having a chance to synchronize.